# How do I access my django app on other devices in my environment using some custom domain?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, localhost, domain-name

I have a django app which I hosted locally on my system, now since other devices are connected and on the same local network as my django app, they too are able to access the website by typing the ipaddress:port of my django app host device.

But I wanted those devices also to access my django app using some domain name, but it's not working. Here is what I tried.

Edited the hosts file on windows and added

```
127.0.0.1 anythingyoulike.com 
127.0.0.1 www.anythingyoulike.com
127.0.0.1. blog.anythingyoulike.com
```

added our custom domain to the allowed host on our settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.anythingyoulike.com', 'blog.anythingyoulike.com', 'anythingyoulike.com']
```

But other devices on my hotspot network are unable to access using these domain names, and only my devices where I hosted my django website is able to access it.

**Note** : There are Android mobile devices too where I want to access using domain name on my local environment

Comment: Did you update all the clients or just the web server?  You need to do it on your clients. Depending on the capabilities of your router, you may be able to do something there more globally.

Comment: What do I need to update in all my clients? they are android device! Also since its mobile hotspot what changes can I do there

Comment: Yes, making a hosts file change on one device is specific to that device and name resolution "out". To make a global name change, you would have to configure whatever mechanism you use for global DNS resolution. If you have not manually set a dns server on your devices to something like 8.8.8.8 then you probably get name resolution from your router and that means you might be able to edit something on your router to global resolve to an internal ip address. Probably asking for help on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ might be a best next move

Comment: check out: https://superuser.com/questions/1548070/hosts-file-but-for-whole-network

Comment: This question is _off-topic_ for Stack Overflow. You seem to have done the programming part correctly and only want to configure your local network. These kind of questions belong to either Server Fault or Super User (Read through their help centers before asking, and also check for potential duplicates). The comments above by @JonSG should be able to get you started on solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something it's a bit mixed up here. As I see you have appended the desired domain names to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` which is completely correct.

After that you have updated the `hosts` file on the server (your laptop). This enables the server to translate the given domain name to the `localhost (127.0.0.1)`, so you can access your django app using the domain on the server itself.

The problem is that the clients (android devices in your case) still don't know that they have to translate those domain names into the ip address of the host. In other words you have to update the `hosts` files on the clients, not on the server. For that purpose I suggest you to check out the following links:

[How to modify the hosts file on your Android device](https://www.modmy.com/how-modify-hosts-file-your-android-device)

[How to edit 'etc/hosts' file in non-rooted phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/174515/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file-in-non-rooted-phone)

I hope this helped :)

Comment: is it possible to make changes in the network level, like some changes in hotspot dns setting to map ip to domain name

Comment: Isn't there any option at a more global level in my local environment?

Comment: In an upper level you may want to setup your own dns server

Comment: For my mobile hotspot how do I do that

Comment: It should be set up on your laptop which is connected to the mobile hotspot. Then other devices that are connected to the hotspot should use your own DNS. You can change DNS in wifi settings on android phones.

Comment: Any blog, youtube video?

Comment: I haven't done this on windows but on linux this may help: [link](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/01/install-dns-server/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual studio for code with your partners Visual studio has function for work multiple coder in one code

If you want to become server and share output of your code connect with your friends one wifi and for your settings.py

settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS="Your connected wifi's ip"
```

and run your server like

windows: python manage.py runserver ip:8080

mac and linux: python3 manage.py runserver ip:8080

Answer (score 0):

first pass your allowed host urls

```
1. ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.anythingyoulike.com',
   'blog.anythingyoulike.com', '127.0.0.1', 'anythingyoulike.com']
```

then

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'
ROOT_HOSTCONF = 'project.hosts'
DEFAULT_HOST = 'www'
PARENT_HOST = 'anythingyoulike.com'
HOST_PORT = "8000"
```

it worked for me

Comment: It didn't work for me, I was not able to access the hosted django app on my android phone using the domain name.
Can you make a video of it and share the link with me, I ll award the bounty to you then. With your laptop hosting the website and you accessing the website using domain on your android phone

Comment: @PulkitBhatnagar did you set same primary dns on you every device like google public dns  8.8.8.8 or  8.8.4.4

Comment: how do I make that changes on my android devices?

Comment: watch a youtube video or read a blog about that

Comment: I didn't get what exactly you want me to do, how do I set the custom domain in my hotspot network is my question

Comment: i want to set all you device priamary dns same

Comment: I saw one video, but that is actually changing the dns server, I need to apply custome domain to a specific ip in my environment